# Launch dscutil in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, command-line, terminal, arguments, dscl

How would I use `dscl` in Objective-C and obtain its output? The command I want to pass as if it is in Terminal is:

```
dscl . -readall /Users UniqueID | awk '/^RecordName:/ {name=$2}; /^UniqueID: / {if ($2 > 500) print name}'
```

I know how to launch system_profiler with arguments such as -xml, etc. but I can't figure out how to pass such a long string in where is actually works.

I know system_profiler is /usr/sbin/system_profiler, but what about dscl?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to launch that as if it were a shell script.  Either stick it in your project as a shell script in a file or use `NSTask` to compose a command line that invokes /bin/sh, passing the command as a string to allow `sh` to parse it.

I.e. `/bin/sh -c ".... your command string ...."`

Comment: Tried: outFileData =[taskLauncher launchTask: @"usr/sh" withArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", @"dscl . -readall /Users UniqueID | awk '/^RecordName:/ {name=$2}; /^UniqueID: / {if ($2 > 500) print name}'", nil]];
Didn't work

Comment: Tried:     outFileData =[taskLauncher launchTask: @"bin/sh" withArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", @"dscl . -readall /Users UniqueID | awk '/^RecordName:/ {name=$2}; /^UniqueID: / {if ($2 > 500) print name}'", nil]]; and it didn't work. Also tried /user/bin/sh

Comment: Did you actually go to the Terminal window and try the command there?   Clearly not.  Do that;  when you get it working in a Terminal, then copy/paste it into your code.   (BTW: The answer is `/bin/sh`)